# chain of shift registers

Tags: verilog, fpga, system-verilog, vlsi

How can I implement this circuit as a chain of shift registers in verilog.

Here a and b are constants and A is a 32-bit register

```
A = A(t-7) + A(t-16) + a.A(t-2) + b.A(t-15) for 16<= t <= 63
```

Thanks

Comment: Is this pseudo code? Algebra? Do parentheses mean multiply or bit number? Is this evaluated iteratively, or is A assigned only once?

Comment: This is pseudo code. A(t-7) means the value of A at time t-7 and new values of A are generated based on the past values of A.

Comment: So should this start `A(t) = `?

Comment: it is an iterative algorithm and it starts at t >=16 and ends at t<=63

Comment: What does a.A(t-2) mean? Is that dot a decimal point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The implementation is the direct mapping of your formula to a shift register and some glue logic, or more formally to a finite state machine. I believe your formula is:

```
for 16<= t <= 63:
A(t)  = A(t-7) + A(t-16) + a.A(t-2) + b.A(t-15)
```

A is your output variable (or output function), whose current value depends on its values at `t-7`, `t-2`, and `t-15`. This means you need to keep its 15 previous values (for example, by using a shift register). Once you have those values, calculating your output is very straightforward.

There are lots of samples on the web for Verilog shift register implementation. The easiest way is to describe a single register module, and then instantiate it multiple times.